# Update using rsync and remove from the source folder

Tags: bash, shell, synchronization, rsync

I want to `rsync` contents from `/local/path` to `server:/remote/path`.

- The files end with extensions composed by 4 digits
- If a file does not exist in remote path, copy the file to remote and remove from local
- If a file exists in remote path and the size is no less than the local one, do not copy the file to remote and remove it from local

I tried

```
rsync -avmhP --include='*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --size-only --remove-source-files /local/path server:/remote/path
```

However, some files existing in the remote path remain in local path.

Another question is, why we need `--include='*/' --exclude='*'`? Why `--include='*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'` alone doesn't work for the file filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `--remove-sent-file` instead of `remove-source-file` ?

According to [the rsync man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)  :

> **`--remove-sent-file`**
>
> This  tells  rsync  to  remove  from  the sending side the files and/or symlinks that are  newly  created  or  whose  content  is updated  on the receiving side. Directories and devices are not removed, nor are  files/symlinks  whose attributes  are  merely changed.

That's means that only transferred file (the ones whom size changed) are deleted from source. To active the include file, you first need to exclude all the other BUT my include pattern. The 3 arguments you used mean "I excluded all files (`--include='*/' --exclude='*'`) but the ones matching my pattern (`--include='*.[0-9]{4}'`)

From man page :

> **`--include=PATTERN`**
>
> don’t exclude files matching PATTERN
>
> **`--exclude=PATTERN`**
>
> exclude files matching PATTERN